# Loop through a list for dataframe column plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have been trying to loop through this list of 19000 tuple and have matplot lib to plot them according the key value of columns in data frame but I could not plot it out.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('/home/xyzcsv')


%matplotlib inline
from pylab import *
with open('list_tuple.txt','rb') as file:
    a = file.readlines()


df = pd.read_csv('20130831_000000.csv')

def createtuple(cola,colb):
    names = df.cola
    names1 = df.colb
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(names)):
        if names[i] <=float(0) or names1[i]<=float(0):
            pass
        else:
            X.append([names1[i],names[i]])
            y.append(i+1)
    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)
    return (X,y)

def plotgraph():
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1],c=y.astype(np.float),alpha=.5)
    plt.show()

for i in range(len(a)):
    b = a[i].split("'")
    (X,y) = createtuple(b[1],b[3])
    plotgraph()
```

The error I got is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-11551e9515fa> in <module>()
     31     b = a[i].split("'")
     32     print b
---> 33     (X,y) = createtuple(b[1],b[3])
     34     plotgraph()

<ipython-input-12-11551e9515fa> in createtuple(cola, colb)
      9 
     10 def createtuple(cola,colb):
---> 11     names = df.cola
     12     names1 = df.colb
     13     X = []

/home/bigdata/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   2667             if name in self._info_axis:
   2668                 return self[name]
-> 2669             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2670 
   2671     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cola'
```

How do I call dataframe column using string concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

Use subscripting to return the column by string name:

```
names = df[cola]
names1 = df[colb]
```

by trying to access the cols as an attribute it fails as `cola` is not an attribute but if you pass the column names to subscript then it will return that column

Also I strongly advise to get into the habit to never access the columns as attributes as it will yield strange behaviour especially if you have column names match an existing attribute or method, for instance you have a column names `sum` then calling `df.sum` returns the address of the method `sum()`